# Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces, and $T_1$ and $T_2$ be linear maps from $U$ to $V$ and $V$ to $U$ respectively, and are onto maps.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces, and $T_1$ and $T_2$ be linear maps from $U$ to $V$ and $V$ to $U$ respectively, and are onto maps.

Are $U$ and $V$ isomorphic?

If both space are finite dimensional then they are isomorphic. But in other cases? I think they are not isomorphic.

But then I am finding it hard to find a counterexample. Any suggestion?

Comment: The spaces will still be isomorphic even if both are infinite. Since there is an onto mapping from each one to the other, in particular this means that both sets have the same cardinality. Choosing bases for each of them, this implies that their bases will also have the same cardinality. Any bijection between basis elements induces an isomorphism in the obvious manner.

Comment: Please format text in normal paragraphs, not equations: it looks awful on small screens otherwise, for one thing. Please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to format equations, but do also look at posts by more experienced users to understand other basic points of style.

Comment: If the question is about algebraic vector spaces, then it does not belong to "functional analysis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (assuming that vector spaces have bases, that is, choice).

Suppose $T\colon U\to V$ is an onto linear map. If $\{v_i:i\in I\}$ is a basis for $V$, choose $u_i$ with $T(u_i)=v_i$, for each $i\in I$.

Then $\{u_i:i\in I\}$ is linearly independent, so it can be extended to a basis. In particular, $\dim V=|I|\le\dim U$ (dimension is the cardinality of a basis).

Comment: if both have uncountable basis.then how can we define the isomorphism  between them

Comment: Infinite basis does not mean uncountable basis. ^

Comment: @Eklavya Just take a bijection between the bases and extend by linearity.